# Why can't I hear audible pings?

Tags: sound, ping

The [ping manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/ping.8.html) says that `ping -a` will generate audible pings, but when I try this no sound is made.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see also [Terminal bell doesn't ring](http://askubuntu.com/q/228096/19466)

Comment: See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1668859

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From looking at the source, ping produces a bell by printing the ASCII bell char '\a', which is doing nothing, probably because the system beep is disabled.

You can manually try to produce the bell with:

```
echo -e "\a"
```

Comment: That's helpful. I'll troubleshoot the bell.

Comment: This is likely a Compiz bug. If you disable Desktop Effects, you will probably hear the pings.

Comment: Yep, here is your bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/537703

Comment: No ping or audio from the `echo` command on CrunchBang Linux (OpenBox) with no compiz.

Comment: @DylanMcCall thank you for providing a  link to the relevant bug report. I added  me to the "this effects me". I hope this gets fixed some time. Wow, in ten days this bug report is seven years old!

Answer (score 10):

`compiz` "eats" the sound and *this is a reported bug*, so it won't work in the graphical interface in standard `compiz` ubuntu sessions. (see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/537703), thanks to Dylan McCall comment for the URL).

If you really need the functionality, you could run your `ping` from a physical console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). But don't forget:

```
sudo modprobe pcspkr
```

As module `pcspkr` isn't loaded at boot time and actually drives the old PC speaker you should have in your computer.

You can add it to `/etc/modules` if you think you'll need it at a regular basis as this will have the effect to tell the system to load it at boot time.

**Note:** as it's a `compiz` issue, if you are using `gnome-fallback` session you shouldn't experience the issue. If this is the case, check your terminal program for options related to console bell.

Answer (score 3):

[1](https://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Beep_Audible_Bell_Ping_Fix) says it's missing a sound file. You can add it with the following command:

```
  pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg bell.ogg
```

For a permanent solution add the command to ~/.xprofile

Answer (score 2):

Because the question is not specified for Unity only, I'll make a little hint about KDEs  Konsole. You just should specify a sound for a "Bell in Visible Session" which is under *Settings -> Configure Notifications*. For example I'm using sounds from */usr/share/sounds/* section. I don't remember is there such an option in Ubuntu's Unity terminal.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I am using KDE in Kubuntu.  I had to tick a checkbox:

1. Search applications for `Notifications`, subtitle is `Event Notifications and Actions`
2. Then under `Applications` select `Konsole`.
3. Then select `Configure Events...`
4. Then highlight `Bell in Non-Focused Session`
5. Then tick next to `Play a sound`

Comment: Thanks, this answer is suitable for recent Plasma versions (mine is 5.22.5). Still haven't figured out how to do the same under Terminator, though. But thanks, at any rate.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, audible bell was disabled because of `xset -b` in my ~/.xsession file and could be re-enabled with `xset b`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Terminator as terminal on Ubuntu 18.10, left-click the Terminator, select preferences/profiles, and there is the audible beep option.

Answer (score 0):

In my case; I just had to turn on/up the 'system sounds' in settings. (see screenshot)

[image: Screenshot of ubuntu's sound settings panel]