# Terminal bell doesn't ring

Tags: sound, teminal-bell

I'd like to get the terminal bell playing through my speakers, but so far I haven't had any luck. I've tried the suggestions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40171/terminal-bell-without-a-pc-speaker) as well as a number of other sources, but I haven't had any luck.

I've also gone the route of un-blacklisting pcspkr in modprobe, but that only works for the `beep` command, not the terminal bell, `echo -e '\a'`, `ping -a`, etc. I don't have a "PC Beep" option in `alsamixer`